# Formula expression to result

Tags: java

In Java, if I have a string:

```
String abc = "(5)*(2+2)/(2)";
```

How could I get the result of `abc = 10`?

Comment: @Touko: that question was restricted to JVM 1.5 solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import javax.script.*;
public class EvalScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        // create a JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // evaluate JavaScript code from String
        Number number = (Number)engine.eval("(5)*(2+2)/(2)");
        System.out.println("abc = " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like `Number number = (Number)engine.eval("(5)*(2+2)/(2)");` instead of using the `print` statement?

Comment: Great solution though and by the way this is only available for Java 6.0 onwards.

Comment: This is a bad solution. It's risky with respect to general security. There are many incidents in which use of a wide open eval tool has been used to compromise systems. Malicious hackers see this kind of code and jump for joy. It's wide open to command injection.

Comment: Not all software is published in open. For quick prototyping this may be a perfect application.

Answer (score 1):

It's not straightforward. You should

- have a grammar for arithmetic expressions
- build a lexer/parser from the grammar
- parse your string with the parser, and have the parser perform the semantic actions corresponding to the arithmetic operators of your grammar.

You can find a simple example in [ANTLR documentation](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3): section 2.1 Create a simple grammar, has a Java example with a grammar for basic arithmetic expressions.

Comment: I agree. Techniques based on any eval mechanism are usually open to injection attacks. Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1-Injection. An example of a commercial tool built for this job is at formula4j.com.